# Restore deleted Mac App Store on 10.8.2

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, calendar

I accidentally deleted system apps like the `App Store.app` and the `Calendar.app`.

How can I restore these? I've tried the combo update like suggested for 10.6.6 systems, but that unfortunately doesn't seem to work on 10.8.

Comment: How did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to recovery HD and reinstall Mountain Lion if you don't have those backed up to your Time Machine (or equivalent) backup.

Comment: I hoped not having to reinstall

Comment: Backups help not having to reinstall when you delete things - you could see about copying those apps from another similar OS install or hope the 10.8.3 combo update has those apps in their entirety.

Comment: Yes I just thought of that. I actually have a mini server running 10.8.2 as well, so I'll try just copying it over from there.

Comment: Consider backing things up just in case calendar barfs. I can't see it being risky, but you never know....

Comment: I usually have a TM backup but this time I just wiped the Time Capsule moments before that to run a completely fresh backup... so bad timing.